# Koin inject to viewModels android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, koin

I have decided to switch from Dagger to Koin because is more lightweight and less code.
So i have my modules as like that

```
val databaseModule = module {

   single {
        get<AppDatabase>().serverDao()
    }
   
    // And all the DAOs here
}

val repositoryModule = module {

   single<ServerRepository> {
        // ServerDao, AccountDao, ApiManager
        return@single ServerRepositoryImpl(get(), get(), get())
    }

    // And all the repositories here

}

val networkModule = module {
    single<Gson> {
        val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
        return@single gsonBuilder.setLenient().create()
    }

    single {
        if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) return@single null

        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        return@single httpLoggingInterceptor
    }

    single {
        return@single HeaderInterceptor()
    }

    single {
        return@single BaseUrlHolder(BuildConfig.BASE_HOLDER_URL)
    }

    single {
        val loggingInterceptor = get<Interceptor?>()
        OkHttpClient().newBuilder().apply {
            connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            loggingInterceptor?.let {
                addInterceptor(it)
            }
            addInterceptor(get<HeaderInterceptor>())
        }.also {
            return@single it.build()
        }
    }

    single<Retrofit> {
        return@single Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(get()))
            .client(get<OkHttpClient>())
            .build()
    }

    single<MyApiService> {
        return@single get<Retrofit>().create(MyApiService::class.java)
    }
}

val managersModule = module {
    single<ApiManager> {

        // I have to provide the URL runTime because it is not standar
        //  private val baseUrlHolder: BaseUrlHolder,
        //  private val retrofitBuilder: Retrofit.Builder
        return@single ApiManagerImpl(get(), get())
    }
```

So in my SplashView i want to have the ServerRepository and the ApiManager.
I tried to get them through the KoinComponent but nothing

```
   // *****BaseViewModel implements KoinComponent*****
   class SplashViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

      // Here i should get the serverRepository.
      private val serverRepository: ServerRepository by inject()
      ......

   }
```

And in the SplashActivity i get the viewmodel as

```
private val splashViewModel: SplashViewModel by viewModels()
```

I always get the same error

```
 Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder'. Check your definitions!
```

Answer (score 0):

Bean definition for the ViewModel has to be defined

```
val viewModelModule = module {
     viewModel {
         SplashViewModel() // if there are no parameter otherwise use get() function to pass the parameter of the viewmodel 
     }  
}
```

Comment: Nop...same problem. I think that the error is on the networkModule. It says No definition found for class:'retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder'

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that i hadn't written correctly the networkModule

```
single<OkHttpClient> {
        val loggingInterceptor = get<Interceptor?>()
        val httpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient().newBuilder().apply {
            connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            addInterceptor(get<HeaderInterceptor>())
            loggingInterceptor?.let {
                addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            }
        }
        return@single httpClientBuilder.build()
    }

    single<Retrofit.Builder> {
        return@single Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(get()))
            .client(get<OkHttpClient>())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you ask an instance of `Retrofit.Builder`

```
val managersModule = module {
    single<ApiManager> {

        // I have to provide the URL runTime because it is not standar
        //  private val baseUrlHolder: BaseUrlHolder,
        //  private val retrofitBuilder: Retrofit.Builder
        return@single ApiManagerImpl(get(), get())
    }
```

In dependency graph you provide only `Retrofit` instead of `Retrofit.Builder`

Changes in the following lines might fix the situation:

```
single<Retrofit.Builder> { // change type
        return@single Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(get()))
            .client(get<OkHttpClient>())
            // Remove
            //.build()
    }

single<MyApiService> {
        // adjustment
        return@single get<Retrofit.Builder>().build().create(MyApiService::class.java)
    }
```